# How do I Bind to a value stored in an Array or Dictionary? Bizarre/Inaccurate Errors reported by Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, binding, swiftui

Can anyone explain why this is not allowed...

Given the following class:

```
class CandidateAttribute  {
    var attributeType : AttributeType
    var name : String
    var value = ""

    init(attributeType: AttributeType) {
        self.attributeType = attributeType
        self.name = attributeType.wrappedName
        self.value = ""
    }
}
```

And a class that has a `Dictionary` of these objects:

```
class Wrapper {
      var candidates : [String: CandidateAttribute]()

      // other code

    func getCandidateAttribute(attributeType: AttributeType) -> CandidateAttribute{
        if let candidate = attributesDict[attributeType.wrappedName] {
            return candidate
        }

        let newCandidate = CandidateAttribute(attributeType: attributeType)
        attributesDict[attributeType.wrappedName] = newCandidate
        return newCandidate
    }
}
```

Why can't I bind to a `CandidateAttribute.value` in the following code:

```
    private func addAttributeRow(attributeType: AttributeType) -> some View {
        let candidateAttr = candidateItem.getCandidateAttribute(attributeType: attributeType)
        return HLabelTextField(label: candidateAttr.name,
                         hint: "Set value",
                         value: $candidateAttr.value) //candidateAttr.value)
    }
```

With the code

```
       return HLabelTextField(label: candidateAttr.name,
                        hint: "Set value",
                        value: candidateAttr.value)
```

I get the error `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'`

With the code:

```
       return HLabelTextField(label: candidateAttr.name,
                        hint: "Set value",
                        value: $candidateAttr.value)
```

I get the error `Use of unresolved identifier '$candidateAttr'`

Is this down to:

1. a bug in my code?
2. a language limitation (Binding to objects stored in arrays is not allowed)?
3. Something else (e.g. I'm holding it wrong)?

If the reason is 2 that seems like a pretty poor language feature to me. The more I use SwiftUI the more I find it requires a lot of work-arounds because things don't 'just work'

Note: I have also tried making `CandidateAttribute` a `struct` as well...

As a workaround I can modify `CandidateAttribute`  and add the following function:

```
    func getValueBinding() -> Binding<String> {

        let binding = Binding<String>(get: { () -> String in
            return self.value
        }) { (newValue) in
            // This func updates the database
            self.value = newValue
        }
        return binding

    }
```

and change the referencing code to:

```
    private func addAttributeRow(attributeType: AttributeType) -> some View {
        let candidateAttr = candidateItem.getCandidateAttribute(attributeType: attributeType)
        return HLabelTextField(label: candidateAttr.name,
                         hint: "Set value",
                         value: candidateAttr.getValueBinding()) //candidateAttr.value)
    }
```

But that feels like way too much code to simply reference a value.

Comment: `$candidateAttr` variable isn't declared - hence the error. `$` prefix for a variable `someVar` only exists when there is a [property wrapper](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID617) around that variable, and then `$someVar` is its projected value. SwiftUI makes any `@State` variables' projected values - e.g. their `$`-prefixed counterparts, a binding, which you can then use like you see in many SwiftUI examples

Comment: Thanks - annotating CandidateAttribute.value with @State and using                          `value: candidateAttr.$value) //getValueBinding())` in the calling code compiles.

Comment: Is your issue solved by that?

Comment: @Edudjr unfortunately not - the code compiles but the value is not updated, unlike with my `getBindingValue()` workaround.

Comment: @mark - I asked a similar question (and provided my own version) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62103647/how-to-generate-a-binding-for-each-array-element. There's apparently a pattern for this (though it didn't work for me)