# What is the correct data type for binding variable of an array's element?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a struct of that is a part of the data set as below:

```
var exercise: [Exercise]


struct Exercise: Codable {
    var id = UUID()
   var exercise, set: Int
}
```

In my code (`View1`) I loop through the exercise array and reach each element like:

```
ForEach(exercise, id: \.id){ item in
   NavigationLink( destination: NextView(arrayItem: item)){
        Text("\(item.exercise)")
   }
}
```

So the `item` I will send to `NextView` must be something like `Exercise(id: E21, exercise: 227, set: 1)`

In the `NextView` I do not know how to define this binding variable. I tried this:

```
struct NextView: View {
     @Binding var arrayItem: Exercise
}
```

The above variable (`arrayItem`) does not match with the item I set in the `View1`.
Any idea what `arrayItem` must be like to accept the `item` value?

This is the error I get:

> 'NextView.Type' is not convertible to '(Binding<Exercise>, Binding<String>, Int) -> NextView'

Comment: I had a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62104068/968155, and found an approach that works, though there might be better ones

Comment: @NewDev thanks fro your comment. However, I find the answer very complicated as I have seen similar solutions for defining and binding values of structs they just didn't work on my code. Hence I decided to post it.

Comment: What about making it an ObservableObject? And in NextView define @ObservedObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions can be to use `@ObservableObject` and make your `exercises` list `@Published`.

First you need some class to store your exercises:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var exercises = [
        Exercise(exercise: 227, set: 1),
        Exercise(exercise: 13, set: 2),
        Exercise(exercise: 423, set: 2)
    ]
}
```

In the NavigationLink you pass the binding of your chosen item - you can do this because you *observe* the `ViewModel` now.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.exercises, id: \.id) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: NextView(exercise: self.$viewModel.exercises[self.viewModel.exercises.firstIndex(of: item)!])) {
                        Text("\(item.exercise)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the `NextView` you can use your `@Binding` variable as needed (I tried modifying the `exercise.exercise` value:

```
struct NextView: View {
    @Binding var exercise: Exercise

    var body: some View {
        Text("Exercise: \(exercise.exercise)")
            .onTapGesture {
                self.exercise.exercise += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly your model needs to conform to `Equatable` - you can't use `firstIndex(of:)` without it:

```
struct Exercise: Codable, Equatable {
    var id = UUID()
    var exercise, set: Int
}
```