# SwiftUI - How to update @state variable from another view with a string from Firebase?

Tags: ios, swiftui

So my problem is that I want to change the country name in the main view from a name in a different view (*which is not a binding variable but a string*) coming from Firebase?

So here is my main `ContentView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showModal: Bool = false
    @State var country: String = "Netherlands"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                // ...
            }) {
                RaceView(showModal: $showModal, country: country)
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
                RaceModalView(showModal: self.$showModal, country: self.$country)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Its showing the `RaceView` as a button, and on click the `RaceModalView` will show as a (sheet) modal.

In the `RaceModalView` it is showing a list of multiple `RaceView`'s based on data coming from Firebase. Here is the `RaceModalView`:

```
struct RaceModalView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = RacesViewModel()
    @Binding var showModal: Bool
    @Binding var country: String

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(viewModel.races){ race in
                RaceView(showModal: self.$showModal, country: race.country)
            }
        }.onAppear {
            self.viewModel.fetchData()
        }
    }
}
```

In the `RaceView` its showing the country name as a button which toggles the actual modal (above). Here is the `RaceView`:

```
struct RaceView: View {
    @Binding var showModal: Bool
    var country: String

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showModal.toggle()
        }) {
            Text(country)
        }
    }
}
```

So I am using a normal variable `country` in this `RaceView`. But when I change this to a binding variable it throws the error:

`Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'`

Because in the RaceModalView where it creates the list its passing a string instead of an expected binding. But this `country: race.country` is coming from Firebase as a string. I can't change it to `race.$country`.

How am I able to update the `@State var country` in the main `ContentView`?

Comment: Show your RacesViewModel.

Comment: I've updated my question, with the RacesViewModel code as well. Also added the onAppear where the fetchData is being called.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example please give us an example where we can reproduce(!) your error and show us the line where the error appears

Comment: So, you're saying that `race.country` works in `Text(race.country)`, but it says it doesn't have member `.country` on a line below it in `RaceView(.... , raceCountry: race.country, ...)`?! That's not possible with the code you've shown, so the error is elsewhere (i.e. your code in question wouldn't reproduce the error)

Comment: Please add `RaceView` code

Comment: @NewDev That's also the part that I don't understand.

Comment: @NikzJon I've updated my question

Comment: @Bobbify - might be related to the error (or not), but since `RaceView` expects a binding, you need to supply it with a binding to a property of `race`. This isn't trivial to do given that you get `race` is an element of a collection passed to `List`. See this question for a way to get to the binding of each list element: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62104068/968155

Comment: Try using `List(viewModel.races.indices) { id in` instead. And use `self.$viewModel.races[id].date`. Hope this help.

Comment: @NikzJon I tried that but didn't help :(. I've cleaned up all my example codes and rephrased my question. Instead of starting with the errors, I am asking how to do what I want to achieve. Hope it clears up a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution use an action to update the binding.

RaceModalView.swift

```
struct RaceModalView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = RacesViewModel()
    @Binding var showModal: Bool
    @Binding var country: String

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(viewModel.races){ race in
                RaceView(showModal: self.$showModal, country: race.country) {
                    self.country = race.country
                }
            }
        }.onAppear {
            self.viewModel.fetchData()
        }
    }
}
```

RaceView.swift

```
struct RaceView: View {
    @Binding var showModal: Bool
    var country: String
    var action: () -> () = {}

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.action()
            self.showModal.toggle()
        }) {
            Text(country)
        }
    }
}
```